# Medium time format to 24 hours time

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I just want to convert HH:mm:ss a(7:11:24 AM) to "hh:mm:ss" only(7:11:24). I am attaching my code, but it gives wrong time.
Any help will be appriciate.

```
func getTime() {
       let dateAsString = "7:11:24 AM"
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss a"
       let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"            
       let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `HH` means 24 hours and `hh` means 12 hour format with am-pm

Comment: Hello Nirav,
I want 24 hours time but not with AM and PM.Is that possible?

Comment: yes possible. your string contains am-pm date so first date format should be `hh:mm:ss a` not `HH`. see my answer.

Comment: In your code change `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss a"` ***To*** `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"`. and  change `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"` ***To*** `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss"`. Then you will het the output ***7:11:24***

Answer (score 4):

you have just place `hh` and `HH` at wrong place.

replace your `hh` with `HH` and

`HH` with `hh`

e.g.

```
let dateAsString = "7:11:24 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!) //output will be - 19:11:24
```

Comment: It gives crash 
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
on let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

Comment: @poojsfollowal in which line you got crash ? actually, i have run in playground. its working.

Comment: crashes on let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

Comment: just copy-paste my code and run in swift playground. let me know if you face still any error then.

Comment: @NiravKotecha The error the OP is getting "could" be a localisation issue with `a`

Comment: @MadProgrammer , is there any solution for this?

Comment: @poojsfollowal You "could" try using `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` before parsing the `String`, I'm only guessing as to your error though

Comment: Hey @MadProgrammer,Its Done.Thanks